# Is it possible programmatically (on non rooted android phones) to check which servers(url) are the installed apps connecting to in the background?

Tags: android, security

Can a security app check what servers(urls) is another app is trying to connect?

I know about android sandboxing but is there still a way using PackageManager or any other API/technique to get this piece of info programmatically using public SDK only, for Non Rooted android phones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as trying to know what other app is trying to connect to is considered security / privacy violation, if that is allowed you may as well dump individual request.

So it should not be possible to achieve that on a non-rooted android phone.

If you are looking for a way to achieve a similar functionality set the android device to use a proxy / gateway controlled by you, and filter / track URL requests there.

If you will root the device then there are many other possibilities.

Comment: Well yes you are right. I kind of thought so. I was trying to figure out could we have a security product that can filter/block/alert user about malicious apps based on what servers are they trying to connect to in the background. Any other way apart from going through the gateway/sniffing mechanism? I am doing some study about how and to what extent desktop based security solutions could be implemented to mobile phones

Comment: Since this is not a discussion forum, I suggest you to contact me over facebook / gmail and discuss over there.You could try to alert based on various other heuristics.

Comment: @srinathhs is it possible on rooted device? Does it need special care or we can achieve it through native apis?

Comment: @YuDroid A rooted phone is essentially a special flavor of linux. It would require you to write native programs to find out all established connections. Look for netstat / ss commands. You can get the app name from linking pid to process name as every app is its own process.